# How to toggle show and hide for two forms present in the same div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I have two forms present in a div, form1 is visible when the page loads, and if I click the next button form1 is hidden and form2 is shown, which is working as expected.

Now I want to achieve the reverse of above scenario which is on click of a back button, form2 should be hidden and form 1 is shown.

Here's javascript code I have so far..

```
function switchVisible() {

  document.getElementById("disappear").innerHTML = "";

  if (document.getElementById('newpost')) {

    if (document.getElementById('newpost').style.display == 'none') {
      document.getElementById('newpost').style.display = 'block';
      document.getElementById('newpost2').style.display = 'none';
    } else {
      document.getElementById('newpost').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('newpost2').style.display = 'block';
    }

  }

}
```

So basically I am looking for a way to achieve toggle functionality for two forms present in the same div using javascript and setting their display property.

Comment: Check https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_hide_show.asp

Comment: Check http://api.jquery.com/toggle/ if you'd like to use jquery.

Comment: Your code should work, Share the HTML where you are using `switchVisible()`

Comment: Can you show your HTML code?

Comment: this is my code... https://jsfiddle.net/3phzezfj/

Answer (score 0):

Make two button elements

```
<button id="next"></button>
<button id="back"></button>
```

You can use jquery (or plain javascript) for this, but I personally prefer jquery.

```
$("#next").click(function {
    $("#newpost").hide();
    $("#newpost1").show();
});
$("#back").click(function {
    $("#newpost").show();
    $("#newpost1").hide();
});
```

(Here 'newpost' and 'newpost1' are the id's of the two form elements)
You can use a similar format if you want to use plain javascript.

Add this

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
</head>
```

Comment: don't use that, so I don't really know. I am sorry.

Comment: I don't use that*

Comment: thats fine Quasar, how do I put this into my jquery? This is all very new to me.

Comment: Just add that inside your <head></head> tags

Comment: if I send you a link to what I'm doing, can you inspect it and tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Ok sure. Use jsfiddle.

Comment: Wow, that is a lot of code. Can you just send me the relevant ones? Also, shall I reply to you maybe an hour later? I am presently busy.

Comment: So, did you get it?

Answer (score 0):

Use a variable stepCount and then according to the value of count display appropriate form.

Like initialise the stepCount with 0, then on click of next increment it by 1 and check condition if stepCount is 1 show second form

Similarly from there if back button is pressed decrement the stepCount by 1 and check condition if stepCount is 0 show first form

Do all this on click of appropriate button click event

Answer (score 0):

You can use toggle function to show hide div.

```js
$('#newpost2').hide();
$("#Toggle").click(function() {
  $(this).text(function(i, v) {
    return v === 'More' ? 'Back' : 'More'
  });
  $('#newpost, #newpost2').toggle();
});
```

```css
.one {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: #eee;
  float: left;
}

.two {
  height: 100px;
  width: 150px;
  background: #fdcb05;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='Toggle' class='pushme'>More</button>
<div class="one" id='newpost'>
  <p>Show your contain</p>
</div>
<div class="two" id='newpost2'>
  <p>Hide your contain</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**This fiddle for button disappear:**

```js
  
  
  $("#next").click(function()
    {
        $("#next").hide();
        $("#back").show();
    });
    $("#back").click(function() {
        $("#back").show();
        $("#next").show();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>



<input type="button" id="next" value="Next"/>
<input type="button" id="back" value="Back"/>
```

```
<button class="btn btnSubmit" id="Button1" type="button" value="Click" onclick="switchVisible();">NEXT</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btnSubmit" onclick="previousVisible();" >BACK</button>
```

simply use this jquery:

```
 function switchVisible() 
    {
      $("#newpost").hide();
      $("#newpost2").show();
    }

    function previousVisible()
    {
     $("#newpost").show();
        $("#newpost2").hide();
    }
```

[your updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3phzezfj/3/)

**Or you may do like this:**

```
 <button class="btn btnSubmit" id="Button1" type="button" value="Click" onclick="form(1);">NEXT</button>

    <button type="button" class="btn btnSubmit" onclick="form(2);" >BACK</button>


function form(a)
{
    if(a==1)
    document.getElementById("newpost").style.display="none";
    else
    document.getElementById("newpost2").style.display="block";
}
```

Comment: do you mean newpost2?

Comment: hi! worked perfectly thanks.. only thing is now I need the next button to disappear, how do I do that?

Comment: Wow that's sounds good..!! Same as well for hide   `$("#Button1").hide();`

Comment: I edited my answer to disappear button. See the above fiddle

Answer (score 0):

You can also use link button and provide URL for particular form in this and hide back link button when click on back that time show only Next button.

e.g.

```
<a href="~/form1" style="btn-default" id="btnNext"> Next</a>
<a href="~/form2" style="btn-default" id="btnPrevious"> Previous</a>

$("#btnNext").click(function {
    $("#btnNext").hide();
    $("#btnPrevious").show();
});
$("#btnPrevious").click(function {
    $("#btnPrevious").show();
    $("#btnNext").hide();
});
```